# Почему не работает этот слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 50);
}

header {
  height: 11vh;
  font-weight: 100;
}

header :nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

header :nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -6%;
  font-size: 33px;
}

header :nth-child(2) img {
  padding-right: 1%;
}

header a {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: Peru;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Peru;
}

header :nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -2%;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#section0 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url('bezimeni-27_E1v9oDX.png') no-repeat center/cover;
  color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#section0 div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-style: double;
  /* Стиль границы */
  border-width: 4px;
  padding: 40px 40px 80px 40px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 27%;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  background: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.8);
}

#section0 div h1,
#section0 div h3 {
  margin: 0px
}

#section0 div h3 {
  font-size: 38px;
}

#section0 div a {
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

#section0 div a:hover {
  background: black;
}

#section1 {
  margin-top: -4%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 .p {
  padding-top: 5%;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#section1 .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 280px);
  font-size: 20px;
  grid-gap: 20px 60px;
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#section1 .grid [alt='0'] {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#section1 .grid [alt='1'] {
  padding-top: 30%;
  margin-top: -31%;
  border-top: 3px solid Peru;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#section1 .grid [alt='2'] {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

[alt='0'] {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 262px;
  bottom: 500px;
}

[alt='1'] {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 478px;
  bottom: 500px;
}

[alt='2'] {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 686px;
  bottom: 500px;
}

#section2 {
  background: silver;
  height: 90vh;
}

#section2 .p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

#section2 .p:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 119%;
  left: 47%;
  width: 5%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid Peru;
  content: "";
}

.main {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p><span class="span">DESIGN</span>STUDIO</p>
    <p><img src="0.png" alt="">8 800 000-00-00</p>
    <p><a href="#">Заказать звонок</a></p>
  </header>
  <section id="section0">
    <div class="">
      <h1>РАЗРАБОТКА</h1>
      <h1>ФИРМЕННОГО СТИЛЯ:</h1>
      <h3>от идеи до реализации</h3>
      <a href="#">↓</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section1">
    <p class="p">РАБОТАТЬ С НАМИ <span>ЛЕГКО И ПРИЯТНО</span></p>

    <div class="grid">
      <div class="div0">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-3_qwMWvjt.png#size_60x60" alt='0'>
        <p><span>СОБЛЮДАЕМ СРОКИ</span></p>
        <p>Разрабатываем лучшие креативные идеи и тщательно следим за соблюдением сроков</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div1">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-2_O1bIEFo.png#size_56x60" alt='1'>
        <p><span>ТАЛАНТЛИВЫЕ ДИЗАЙНЕРЫ</span></p>
        <p>Высококвалифицированные профессионалы, которые мыслят ярко и нестандартно</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-1_OmiiQCk.png#size_60x52" alt='2'>
        <p><span>ДОСТУПНАЯ ЦЕНА</span></p>
        <p>Гибкая система расценок позволяет сотрудничать как с крупными компаниями, так и с частными лицами</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-7_UJJtw4y.png#size_126x126" alt="0" class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-5_ltDSD24.png#size_126x126" alt="1" class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-6_X9sbs1e.png#size_126x126" alt="2" class="">

  <section id="section2">
    <p class="p">НАШЕ <span>ПОРТФОЛИО</span></p>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="sl">
        <div class="slide__slide">
          <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-14_29JPQGq.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 1" class="imgSlide__img">
          <div class="sl__text">
            <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 1</h3>
            <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide">
          <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-15_gu3xAbi.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 2" class="imgSlide__img">
          <div class="sl__text">
            <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 2</h3>
            <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide">
          <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-12_2vWLtcK.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 3" class="imgSlide__img">
          <div class="sl__text">
            <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 3</h3>
            <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide">
          <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-13_qOo3I8l.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 4" class="imgSlide__img">
          <div class="sl__text">
            <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 4</h3>
            <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.sl').slick({
      autoplay: true
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Как его починить? Вроде всё делал по коду из оф сайта

Comment: что именно не работает? ошибка какая-то есть? или что? если не разберешься то попробуй owl carousel или swiper(чистый js)

Answer (score 1):

Я не увидел jquery и как подключил его сразу заработало

Вообще мануалы какого то `сомнительного челика` использовать не надо так как есть официальный сайт: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-14_29JPQGq.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 1" class="imgSlide__img">
    <div class="sl__text">
      <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 1</h3>
      <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-15_gu3xAbi.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 2" class="imgSlide__img">
    <div class="sl__text">
      <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 2</h3>
      <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-12_2vWLtcK.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 3" class="imgSlide__img">
    <div class="sl__text">
      <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 3</h3>
      <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-13_qOo3I8l.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 4" class="imgSlide__img">
    <div class="sl__text">
      <h3 class="sl__zag">Слайд 4</h3>
      <p class="sl__desc">Описание Слайда N4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.slider').slick({
    autoplay: true
  })
</script>
```

Comment: как ты не увидел тут jQyery
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src='slick.js'></script>

Comment: у меня ничего не произошло от того, что я что-то поменял

Comment: я исправил код, но ничего не измениллось, посмотри плиз. Папку slick закинул в проект

Comment: @Величайший  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pozyPoW так ?